# Nested custom elements in app.config (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, nested, app-config

G'da to everyone,

For hours I've been trying to figure how to read settings from [app.config](http://pastebin.com/yuz7jLbQ) file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="Databases" type="McFix.DatabaseSection, McFix"/>
  </configSections>

  <Databases>
    <Database name="database">
      <Tables>
        <Table name="be_sessions">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="sess_id">
            </Column>
          </Columns>
        </Table>
      </Tables>
    </Database>
  </Databases>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

The the code for custom handler classes is [here](http://pastebin.com/ZAxQjySe), also copied below:

```
public class DatabaseSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Databases", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    public DatabaseInstanceCollection Databases
    {
        get { return (DatabaseInstanceCollection)this["Databases"]; }
        set { this[""] = value; }
    }
}
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DatabaseElement), AddItemName = "add", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap )]
public class DatabaseInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new DatabaseElement();
    }
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((DatabaseElement)element).Name;
    }
}
public class DatabaseElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }
}

public class TableSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Tables", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public TableInstanceCollection Tables
    {
        get { return (TableInstanceCollection)this["Tables"]; }
        set { this[""] = value; }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(TableElement), AddItemName = "Table", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class TableInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new TableElement();
    }
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((TableElement)element).Name;
    }
}

public class TableElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }
}

public class ColumnSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Columns", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public ColumnInstanceCollection Columns
    {
        get { return (ColumnInstanceCollection)this["Columns"]; }
        set { this[""] = value; }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ColumnElement), AddItemName = "Column", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class ColumnInstanceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ColumnElement();
    }
    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ColumnElement)element).Name;
    }
}

public class ColumnElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I attempt to get "Databases" section via GetSection method:

```
Configuration Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
DatabaseSection DbConfig = Config.GetSection("Databases") as DatabaseSection;
```

program throws an ConfigurationErrorsException, reporting "Unrecognized element 'Database'", although it does that after going through get method of DatabaseSection, even though I define AddItemName for DatabaseInstanceCollection as "Database". Am I missing something, attribute that will let underlying code read the app.config correctly?

Comment: What's wrong with SO formatting?  Also, you'll need to do more work for this.  Describe what didn't work for you and what your problem is.  Nobody is going to read through your code to figure out what went wrong.  Give examples of your failures.

Comment: Are you asking how to read in the config settings using the classes you defined?  I didn't see anything in your code where you actually read it in.

Comment: If you want to post **code, XML** or **data** samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! SO **will** format and display it quite nicely if you do!

Comment: My apologies to everyone, having not posted questions on the forums for a while (mostly because I was answering those of others), I have lost the touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obligatory links:

- [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

After a cursory look it seems like your problem is on this line:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DatabaseElement), AddItemName = "add", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap )]
```

This indicates that the .config file should look like this:

```
<Databases>
    <add><!-- Database goes here --></add>
</Databases>
```

I.e. your `Databases` element is expecting an "add" child, to indicate that an item is to be added to the colleciton.

You should try changing the `AddItemName` property from "add" to "Database":

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DatabaseElement), AddItemName = "Database", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap )]
```

(I've not had a chance to test this, there may be other problems)

Comment: Thanks Kragen, I've browsed Q & A for similar Application Configuration for .NET here and visited links you mentioned before but alas. I have attempted to change AddItemName to "Database" but to no avail either.

I have a suspicion that "Database" element has to be declared for section "Databases", although I would've thought it's done through "AddItemName" property of ConfigurationCollection attribute.

Comment: @user696034 Does it make a difference to the error message?  I've also spotted that the `DatabaseElement` configuration element has no reference to the `TableSection` configuration section, and so I expect that would probably cause a failure even after resolving the above.

Comment: I've managed to get the whole thing going, but you're right Kragen, it was necessary to add TableInstanceCollection to DatabaseElement and ColumnInstanceCollection to TableElement.
Also, the DatabaseSection had to be made like this to work:

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, Kragen, I had to remove Table/ColumnSection and add Table/ColumnInstanceCollection to Database/TableElement. DatabaseSection' Databases property had to be like:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public DatabaseInstanceCollection Databases
        {
            get { return (DatabaseInstanceCollection)this[""]; }
        }
```